# Cross reference in c++ classes

Tags: c++

So I would like to have something along the following lines: object of type A that owns an object of type B, while the object of type B has a reference to the object of type A that is owned by.

I tested the following code and compiles fine using gcc:

```
class A;
class B;

class B {
public:
    B(const A& a);
    const A& m_a;
    int m_data;
};

class A {
public:
    A();
    B m_b;
    int m_data;
};

A::A()
    : m_b(*this)
    , m_data(42) {
    std::cout << "A: this->m_data = " << this->m_data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A: m_b.m_data = " << m_b.m_data << std::endl;
}

B::B(const A& a)
    : m_a(a)
    , m_data(28) {
    std::cout << "B: m_a.m_data = " << m_a.m_data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B: this->m_data = " << this->m_data << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A a = A();
}
```

With the following (expected) output:

```
B: m_a.m_data = 700870728
B: this->m_data = 28
A: this->m_data = 42
A: m_b.m_data = 28
```

So, the question is:
Is this design of classes correct (as long as I don't use the reference of A in the constructor of B, since it is still not constructed) or I might run into some issue? In that case, which would be a good alternative to this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if one of these objects gets copy-constructed? Assigned to from another object?

Comment: Are you sure that [inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_inheritance.asp) is no longer adequate for your purpose?

Comment: Well that is a good point Ikarus, in fact that seems exactly what I need. I didn't really think about it since it didn't make much sense semantically in the context I am working with. I am building a 3D renderer, my class A manages the creation of a window, inside this window lives the 3D renderer application (class B). At the same time, the application has to be aware of the window it is living in so that it can check the state of it (check for inputs for example). Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the proposed code can be compiled and is technically correct (you could also achieve the same functionality if you use a pointer "const A*" instead of the reference "const A&").

However, you must be careful when using cross-references and be aware of the lifetime of each of the involved instances. As you can see in the execution of your example, when B is constructed, m_a.m_data is not yet initialized so you are getting and "undefined behavior" in that first std::cout because you are printing an int which has not been yet initialized (that is why you see a random value 700870728 in the first std::cout).

Similary, when destroying the instances of A and B you may see similar issues if you try to use an attribute of A during the destructor of B, because that attribute may be already destroyed (the attributes of a class are constructed in the order that they are declared, and destructed in the inverse order).

As long as you don't use the cross-references from the constructors and destructors, the usage of the cross-references should be correct.

But from my point of view, if you need a cross-reference like this it means that the code architecture should be reviewed. My suggestion would be to move all the shared functionality between A and B to a new class C, and then both A and B can share the same instance of C, contributing to a more modular, safer and more maintainable code. And I would use C++ smart pointers to ensure that the shared instance of C is destroyed once A and B are done with it. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class C {
public:
    int m_data;
    C() : m_data(22) {
        std::cout << "C: m_data = " << m_data << std::endl;
    }
    ~C() {
        std::cout << "~C: m_data = " << m_data << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<C> m_c;
    B(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : m_c(c) {
        std::cout << "B: m_c->m_data = " << m_c->m_data << std::endl;
    }
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "~B: m_c->m_data = " << m_c->m_data << std::endl;
    }
};

class A {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<C> m_c;
    A(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : m_c(c) {
        std::cout << "A: m_c->m_data = " << m_c->m_data << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A: m_c->m_data = " << m_c->m_data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto c = std::make_shared<C>();
    A a{ c };
    B b{ c };
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's done because it's needed or just because it's possible and technically correct.